# Is fetching one row at a time, from server-side cache/cursor, using Ruby OCI8 gem possible?

Tags: ruby, caching, server-side, oci8, large-data

oci8 gem to query a database and fetch the results; however, the size of the query's results is unknown and may be too large to cache on an individual's computer. Is there a way to query the database, store the results on the server-side and then fetch each record from that set, one by one? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried limiting the query with [oracle's `rownum`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm)

Answer (score 2):

It is the only way which ruby-oci8 supports.

All Oracle cursors are server-side cursors. Fetched records are sent to the client
only when the client requests more rows.
FIY, maximum number of rows in the client-side cache is limited by [OCI8#prefetch_rows=](http://rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-oci8/OCI8#prefetch_rows%3D-instance_method) and [OCI8::Cursor#prefetch_rows=](http://rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-oci8/OCI8/Cursor#prefetch_rows%3D-instance_method). The default value is one.
It is recommended to increase the size to 100 for large data.

Note: The default prefetch row size was changed to 100 in ruby-oci8 2.2.0.